# How container class works in stl?

Tags: c++, interface, iterator

Iterator definition says [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator)]:

> Iterator is an object enables programmer to traverse the container it also says  Various types of iterators are often provided via a container's interface.

[Cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) has a big table in which each container has member as iterator categories function.

So does it mean that each container class has iterator class which implements the base iterator class and various function in this iterator class which would instantiated and work with this container class in order to follow the interface.

My question is how a class allow another class to have interface?

Comment: *"iterator class which implements the base iterator class"* Iterators don't have to inherit from any classes. (There is a deprecated [`std::iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator), but inheriting from it is optional.)
*"how a class allow another class to have interface?"* What do you mean?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes please, without interface keyword.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat in wikipedia "Various types of iterators are often provided via a container's interface"  what this interface means here.

Comment: @ParsuramKailasa It mean that you can obtain the said iterators via the containers interface(public methods). For example to obtain an iterator of an `std::vector` that iterates through the vector from the beginning you have to call the vector's `std::vector::begin()` method.

Comment: @Lorand that word(public method) i was looking for. thank you so much. any resource where i can explore more.

Comment: @ParsuramKailasa Here, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator. This page has the minimum requirements, there are links to pages describing more sophisticated iterator requirements. Note these requirements aren't interfaces in the usual OO sense. They just document how expressions involving iterators are expected to behave. Because of this you can implement iterators in any manner you like, as long as your classes support the required operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ does not have a keyword `interface`. The (public) "interface" of a class *is* it's (public) members. This can include [type aliases](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias).

All the containers provide type aliases named `iterator` and `const_iterator`, which refer to types with the stated properties. They also have public member functions named [`begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) and [`end`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/end), which are overloaded to return that container's `iterator`s and `const_iterator`s.

An [Iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator) is anything for which `++` advances and `*` dereferences. `int *` is one such type, so is `_Tree_iterator<_Tree_simple_types<_Tmap_traits<int, int, ...>>>` <sup>1</sup>

The standard *does not specify* the type that `vector<T>::iterator` et.al. denote, only that it satisfies [RandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator).

1. The (partial) type of Microsoft's version of `std::map<int, int>::iterator`